# Cómo ordenar un listado objetos dependiendo de otra relación Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-7

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

- companies
- modules
- company_modules (una empresa tiene muchos módulos)

In **Company.php**

```
public function companyModules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CompanyModule::class);
}
```

In **CompanyModule.php**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function module()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Module::class);
}
```

El problema es que en **modules** table existe un campo 'order' y necesito un listado de companyModules (company_modules) pero ordenados por el campo **orden** de **modules**.

He intentado colocar esto en **Company.php** pero obviamente es un error:

```
public function companyModulesByOrder()
{
    return $this->companyModules()->orderBy('order', 'ASC');
}
```

No me sirve un listado de modules, porque hay un método en CompanyModule que debo ejecutar, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Tu método `companyModulesByOrder` está haciendo el equivalente a

```
CompanyModule::orderBy('order','ASC')
```

(o sea no es una colección con resultados hasta que hagas `get` sobre ella)

Eso te da un error porque la tabla `company_module` no tiene ese campo. Podrías usar un join

```
 return $this->companyModules()
             ->join('modules','id','module_id')
             ->orderBy('modules.order','ASC')->get()
```

Y si quieres asegurarte de que esté ordenando, puedes añadir la columna de modules en el resultado (que sigue siendo una colección de instancias de CompanyModule)

```
 return $this->companyModules()
        ->select(['company_modules.*', 'modules.order'])
        ->join('modules','id','module_id')
        ->orderBy('modules.order','ASC')->get()
```